# Fetch meetings which are updated last 2 days

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Fetch all the meetings which are updated in the last 48 hours.

I have to consider updated_at from 3 tables and consider which is recently updated.

Meeting belongs to room.

Meeting will be having multiple invites.

If any of the 3 models (meeting, room, invites) changes in the last 48 hours I need to fetch meetings.

Relationships::

```
Class Meeting
   has_many :invites
   belongs_to :room
end

Class Room
  has_many :meetings
end

Class Invite
  has_many :meetings
end
```

Note:: 
I don't need any data from invites, rooms, I need to consider only updated_at for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `:touch` parameter on `activerecord` relation. You might try this:

```
Class Room
   # touch is true will update meeting whenever the room is updated
   has_many :meetings, touch: true
end

Class Invite
  # touch is true will update the meetings whenever the invite is updated 
  has_many :meetings, touch: true
end
```

You can read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more detail. Remember to search for `:touch`.

**Update:**
If you don't want to update meeting whenever its related records are updated. You can manually query all invites, rooms and meetings and collect meetings record from them. Something like this:

```
new_invites = Invite.includes(:meetings).where("updated_at >= ?", Time.zone.now - 48.hours)
new_rooms = Room.includes(:meetings).where("updated_at >= ?", Time.zone.now - 48.hours)
new_meetings = Meeting.where("updated_at >= ?", Time.zone.now - 48.hours)

collected_meetings = new_invites.map(&:meetings).flatten + new_rooms.map(&:meetings).flatten + new_meetings 
result = collected_meetings.uniq { |m| m.id }
```

Comment: I don't want to update meeting when ever room or invite changes. I want to fetch through query.

Comment: Then I think you need to fetch all rooms, invites, meetings that updated in last 48 hours then you collect meetings from that. I will update my answer for this.